# Transferring hash maps over ajax and converting to php array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm making an interpreter for a mini language, and I'm storing related information in hash maps. I'm convering those hash maps with JSON stringify, to send them over via ajax to the server side.

This is is the post-JSON stringify code I'm sending over to the server side:

```
{"kv":["24","23","20"],"interface":"dropdown"},{"ma":["2","3","4"],"interface":"button"}
```

**On the server side**, how could I easily make a php array out of the `"kv":["24","23","20"]` bit without searching for certain characters?

Before sending it over ajax the output of json array is:

```
{"kv":["24","23","20"],"interface":"dropdown"},{"ma":["2","3","4"],"interface":"button"}
```

After receiving it, the data is:

```
{&quot;kv&quot;:[&quot;24&quot;,&quot;23&quot;,&quot;20&quot;],&quot;interface&quot;:&quot;dropdown&quot;},{&quot;ma&quot;:[&quot;2&quot;,&quot;3&quot;,&quot;4&quot;],&quot;interface&quot;:&quot;button&quot;}
```

after the `htmlspecialchars_decode` function, it becomes:

```
{"kv":["24","23","20"],"interface":"dropdown"},{"ma":["2","3","4"],"interface":"button"}
```

`json_decoding` that gives me null

The ajax code:

```
function addValues(jsonArray) {

      alert(jsonArray);

       $.ajax({

        url: 'insertTree.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'dataToReceive=' + jsonArray,
        success: function(data) {
        //called when successful
       alert(data);
        window.location.reload();
        },
        error: function(e) {
        //called when there is an error
        console.log(e.message);
        }
      });

     }
```

the php receiving code:

```
$dataReceived = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST["dataToReceive"]));

$dataRefined = htmlspecialchars_decode($dataReceived);

$var = json_decode($dataRefined, true);

var_dump($var['kv']); //null
```

Comment: You're either going to have to do those two individually or put them in an object.

Comment: Not sure why you're doing all the entities stuff and there is probably a better way to construct it in JS, but you need them in an object: `$var = json_decode("[$dataRefined]", true);`

Comment: i wasn't sure of how to prepare the hash map and best convert it to a string for sending over to the server, it got especially convoluted when i started dealing with an array of hashmaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_decode` to get the value. Since your base string isn't valid JSON, I massaged it a bit to get it to be

```
$string = '{"kv":["24","23","20"],"interface":"dropdown"},{"ma":["2","3","4"],"interface":"button"}';
$data = explode('|', str_replace('},{', '}|{', $string));

foreach($data as $str) {
    $var = json_decode($str, true);
    if(isset($var['kv'])) var_dump($var['kv']);
}
```

Comment: the json decode returns null, i think the json isn't properly formatted? i'll update the question with all of the outputs

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. I took your edited string and massaged it a bit. Above code should work

Comment: ye, the explode correction makes it all clearer now, i can loop through all of the data array entries and fetch the values, thanks a bunch